# SearchView: what are these views for suggestions?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, robotium

I have a `SearchView` in my application, now I'm making functional tests using `Robotium` library. When user starts to type in search query the following views with suggestions are shown:

[image]

I need to verify those suggestions are on the screen. So questions are:

1. What are these views themselves?
2. How to verify those views are shown on the screen? I tried to use `solo.searchForText()`, but this didn't work for me.

Comment: I havent actually tried to automate these views. What shows in the emulator on the viewhierarchy?

Comment: I have found it, it's PopupWindow.

Comment: I will get to check this out for you soonish, i hope!

Comment: How did you manage to type into the searchview after the magnifying glass is clicked using robotium?

Comment: I face the same problem, how did you manage to set text in searchview with robotium ?

Comment: Finally my solution to type into searchview is : 1. Get searchView view // final View tSearchView = mSolo.getView(R.id.action_product_search); 2. Cast it and then set text into it //((SearchView) tSearchView).setQuery("8319993", true); //set true or false to submit query or not. Hope it'll help !